# I got an issue of rake assets pre-compile in Open Project source

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, github, precompile

I am new in `Open Project source` of `GitHub`. I am facing issue of file not found when pre-compile.

Below error:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bundles/openproject-global'
```

Any one have a idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but you probably need to run both

```
npm install
```

and

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```